# Derive the generating function: $\frac1{(1-x)^3}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, generating-functions

> $$\frac1{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}2x^n$$

I am not sure how to begin.

$$\begin{aligned}\frac1{1-x}&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\\\frac1{(1-x)^2}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}\end{aligned}$$

Then you would get:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{2n - 1}$$

Which is nowhere near the same...?

Comment: How did you get from each line to the next?

Comment: I think your second derivative is wrong.  Should be $\sum n(n-1)x^{n-2}$. And note that the binomial coefficient ${n+2}\choose{2}$ is very similar to $n(n-1)$.

Comment: $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n.\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n\neq  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nb_n$.

Comment: Expand $(1-x)^{-3}$ using the Binomial Theorem for negative exponents and you're done.

Comment: In general, $~\dfrac1{(1-x)^{k+1}}~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+k}kx^n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, indeed, $\dfrac 1 {1-x} = \sum \limits _{n=0} ^\infty x^n$. As you tried to do, let us differentiate this twice. The first time you get

$$\frac 1 {(1-x)^2} = \sum \limits _{n=1} ^\infty n x^{n-1}$$

(note that the sum starts from $1$ now, not from $0$). Differentiating once more, you get

$$\frac 2 {(1-x)^3} = \sum \limits _{n=2} ^\infty n(n-1) x^{n-2}$$

and, if you change the summation variable according to $m = n-2$, you get

$$\frac 2 {(1-x)^3} = \sum \limits _{m=0} ^\infty (m+2)(m+1) x^m\;,$$

which is your desired result because

$$\binom {m+2} 2 = \frac {(m+2)!} {m! \ 2!} = \frac {(m+2)(m+1)} 2\;.$$

Comment: Alex.  It won't change the flow of your post, but $\frac{d(1-x)^{-1}}{dx}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\ne -\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$.  Happy Holidays.  _ Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: Ha! Yes, too much wine for Christmas!

Comment: I know what you mean.  ;-) And +1 now!

Comment: (+1) Why does $n= 0 \to n=2$ in the last steps? Why do we change the index?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Why the change from "deriving" to "differentiating"? This is not a tragedy, but I'm usually careful about the language I use; to me the two words are closely-related, yet different. I don't compute the differential ${\rm d}f$, but the derivative $f'$ (it's quite like the difference between Gateaux and Frechet).

Comment: @Amad27: Because your problem asks you to present the result as a sum starting from $0$, while I had one starting at $2$. The trick was to translate $n$ back by $2$ through the formula $m = n-2$.

Comment: @Alex: Because taking a derivative is differentiating; deriving is what you do when you produce a (logical or computation) derivation of something. I consider your use of *deriving* a foreignism.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of both sides

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left (\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \right) = \frac{d}{dx} \left ( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n-1} \right)$$

$$-(-2)\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  n (n-1) x^{n-2}$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{n (n-1)}{2} x^{n-2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(n +2) (n+1)}{2} x^{n}.$$

Look at the definition of the binomial coefficient and you'll see that this is the same as the desired formula.

Answer (score 0):

We will show that, for all $k\geq 0$:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \binom{n+k}{k}x^n$$

For $k=0$, this is clear (and if we are clever, we can even start at $k=-1$).  We have:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+2}} = \frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \left(\sum_{n\geq 0} x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\geq 0} \binom{n+k}{k}x^n\right)$$

$$= \sum_{n\geq 0} \left(\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{j+k}{k}\right) x^n$$

So it is enough to show: $$\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{j+k}{k} = \binom{n+k+1}{k+1}$$

But this follows from a straightforward induction on $n$, using only the addition in Pascal's triangle.  We can also do this sum directly, using telescoping:

$$\binom{j+k}{k} = \binom{j+k+1}{k+1} - \binom{j+k}{k+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is also convenient to use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{(1-x)^3}&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-3}{n}(-x)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^n
> \end{align*}
>
> Here we use $\binom{-r}{s}=\binom{r+s-1}{s}(-1)^s=\binom{r+s-1}{r-1}(-1)^s$